# How to manage related controllers inside in one folder in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my application there are 3 controller related to employee.Right now they are inside controller folder.

```
heronhrm/app/controllers
employeename_controller.rb
employeeaddress_controller.rb
employeelist_controller.rb
```

Now all are working fine. Now i want to list all employee related controllers inside employees folder like,

```
heronhrm/app/controllers/employees
employeename_controller.rb
employeeaddress_controller.rb
employeelist_controller.rb
```

Now what changes should i do in my code to work in this case also like first. for example in my views, model etc.

Comment: Do you really mean controllers? The Rails convention for controller files is like `employee_controller.rb` with `EmployeeController` class inside. What you show here looks more related to the model. Or do you have a separate controller for managing every single attribute of Employee?

Comment: sorry i edit my question. Yes each controller work differently. just i want to gather 3 controllers in one folder. so that each should work like before they work.. so what changes i have to do. Likewise In views also they should be in employees folder. wherei have to change like routes,...

Comment: search for namespace in rails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to update your routes.rb like this :

```
namespace :employees do
  # all your employees routes here
end
```

And then, like @andrjas said, you have to prefix your controller's name :

```
class Employees::EmployeenameController < ApplicationController
  # your code here
end
```

Finally move your views into a folder app/views/employees/

Comment: I did as yo say but for employeename_controller.rb to work what shoul i put inside namespace :employees do
  # all your employees routes here
end I did put like    namespace :employees do
    resources :employeename
  end   but i get error like this No route matches [GET] "/employeename"

Comment: You did the right thing, but if you now check rake routes, you will see that the new path to see your employeename must be : GET /employees/employeename. So you have to change your routes everywhere you need in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to change the class name from Employeename to Employees::Employeename (I'd recommend to change Employeename to simply Name, since it's a duplication then), the views should also be in a subdirectory "employees" (I'm guessing here, but that should be the "Rails Way"). The models are not really connected to the controllers and should stay the same here.